# ACL setting for parse object through Java Script

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, acl

I am using the following option to assign ACL for the parse object but ibnstead when the data saves it sets the ACL to Masterkey insted of the user Administrator?! Is it also possible to assign to the current user and the administrator at the same time?

```
createOnEnter: function(e) {
      var self = this;
            this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;

      this.todos.create({
        content: this.input.val(),
        order:   this.todos.nextOrder(),
        done:    false,
        user:    Parse.User.current(),
        ACL:     new Parse.ACL("Administrator") //Parse.User.current())
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I could do this by adding a beforeSave function to cloud but will still accept otehr answers through JavaScript.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Todo", function(request, response) {
  var newACL = new Parse.ACL();

  newACL.setReadAccess("Administrator",  true);
  newACL.setReadAccess("egHA6j8J6D",  true);
  newACL.setReadAccess(Parse.User.current(),  true);

  request.object.setACL(newACL);
  response.success();
});
```